# Unable to resolve module react/lib/ReactUpdates

Tags: ios, react-native, xcode8

I'm cloning a proyect:

**The steps are:**

- npm i
- react-native link

When i run it `react-native run-ios` i have a problem with `RCTWebSocket` library. This problem is easy to resolve if you search a little just need remove 2 compiler flags, in `Custom Compiler Flags`.

Later just i run again `react-native run-ios` and works fine, but when the app is open, show the next error:

[image]

Searching i found that is related to `upgrade`, [source here](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5252)

but i'm using that command and not works.

> When this command is executed, it starts showing me some overrides to some files and at the end of this process, the problem persists.

My react info:

```
react-native-cli: 1.0.0
react-native: 0.32.1
```

I'm running in `Xcode 8` and ios `10.0`

> PDTA: When I start a new project works perfect

***UPDATES:***

When clone on another mac works, I am ensuring to have the same versions of both xcode and node.

Could it be some mac configuration problem?

```
The only difference between the 2 macs is the cli version:

`react-native-cli: 1.1.0` --> my mac
`react-native-cli: 1.2.0` --> the other mac
```

**Will this be enough to cause all this problem?**

Answer (score 27, accepted):

With React 0.32~0.37: The problem is most likely that you are using React 15.4.x instead of 15.3.x. One of the changes between 15.3 and 15.4 was that many of the modules under `react/lib` were moved to `react-dom/lib`, which is why the packager can't find `react/lib/ReactUpdates`.

Ensure that your package.json file locks React to 15.3.x:

```
"dependencies": {
  "react": "~15.3.2"
}
```

Then delete your `node_modules` folder and run `yarn` or `npm install` again. Verify that you installed React 15.3.x:

```
$ npm ls react
app@1.0.0 /code/app
└── react@15.3.2
```

Last, restart the React Native server and load your bundle again.

Comment: This works for me as well, so do I understand correctly that this is a dependency issue from another package that's not build for react 15.4 yet?

Comment: I face the same issue with react-native 0.38. Should it work?

Answer (score 1):

This has been fixed!

Update your dependencies and use `react-native ^0.38.0` or newer.

Run `react-native upgrade` after all react-native version upgrades.