# Uknown named module after upgrading react native 0.37 to 0.39

Tags: react-native

I tried to upgrade my react-native version by following (upgraded react module and react-native)

https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/upgrading.html

after I ran `react-native upgrade` I have added changes I had in AndroidManifest.xml, MainActivity.java, MainApplication.java, String.xml

I have successfully built and ran the app. But when the assets gets loaded and app starts on my device i get error.

> Unknown named module: 'react/lib/createReactNativeComponentClass'

I saw this one on Chrome when debbuging

> Module AppRegistry is not a registered callable module (calling runApplication)

I have tried to search for this problem but i didnt find anything that could help me. Only thing i didnt try is to start with clean installation and see if that helps me (but i would like to avoid that if possible).

And also my package.json

```
{
  "name": "MyProject",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "react": "^15.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.39.2",
    "react-native-action-bar": "^1.0.8",
    "react-native-background-timer": "^0.1.3",
    "react-native-drawer": "^2.3.0",
    "react-native-fcm": "^2.3.2",
    "react-native-gifted-spinner": "^0.1.0",
    "react-native-infinite-scroll-view": "^0.4.2",
    "react-native-linear-gradient": "^1.5.15",
    "react-native-maps": "^0.12.2",
    "react-native-pathjs-charts": "0.0.21",
    "react-native-radio-buttons": "^0.13.0",
    "react-native-scrollable-mixin": "^1.0.1",
    "react-native-scrollable-tab-view": "^0.7.0",
    "react-native-swipe-list-view": "^0.3.1",
    "react-native-swiper": "^1.5.3",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^3.0.0"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "jest-react-native"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "17.0.0",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "1.9.0",
    "jest": "17.0.0",
    "jest-react-native": "17.0.0",
    "react-test-renderer": "15.3.2"
  }
}
```

In Version 0.37 everything work as it should. But i needed an update since i saw some fixes in change log that i found useful. So i tried to update but with no success.

Comment: This may Help, http://stackoverflow.com/a/40737409/3666700

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Vkrm gave me a good direction with this link

[stackoverflow.com/a/40737409/3666700](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40737409/3666700)

> One of the changes between 15.3 and 15.4 was that many of the modules under react/lib were moved to react-dom/lib,

With this in mind i tried to downgrade react to 15.3 and it worked. But was getting some errors with third-party components and react-native 0.39 works best with 15.4 (but will work with 15.3 you might get a warning).

I went to search more and found this thread
[stackoverflow.com/a/41352829/1393695](https://stackoverflow.com/a/41352829/1393695)

> Delete your node_modules folder and run "npm install" again (or use yarn if you want this step to be fast). Make sure package.json specifies the latest version of React Native that you expect.

After that i backed up my project again and emptied `node_modules` folder and ran `npm install` and after that it worked well with 15.4. but got errors with third party components (which i changed).

So it works both ways but might cause some errors with third-party components.